# prevent vim grep from opening first matching file

Tags: vim, grep

So, fiddling with the EasyGrep.vim plugin, trying to get it into a state that suits me.
I am using it for recursive searching of a Rails project. Ive almost got it how I want it, this is an example of the grep command my modified EasyGrep executes:

```
:grep -R -i  --include=*.rb --include=*.rbw --include=*.gem --include=*.gemspec --include=[rR]akefile --include=*.erb --include=*.rhtml SEARCH_WORD .
```

Which finds the word under the cursor, and opens the search results in quicklist.

Only problem is, :grep seems to automatically open the file containing the first match into the current buffer, which I *do not* want it to do, because then I lose the file I was just looking at.

Anyone know how I can prevent this behavior? Or, at least a hacky workaround that reopens the file I was searching from?

:vimgrep is not an option - its far too slow.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From `:help :grep`:

> `Just like ":make", but use 'grepprg' instead of 'makeprg' and 'grepformat' instead of 'errorformat'.`

From `:help :make`:

> `If [!] is not given the first error is jumped to.`

So: `:grep!`

Comment: As for "a hacky workaround" (that is not necessary here but may still be of use to you), `:help CTRL-^`

Comment: legend! I thought id tried that already(;grep!), but apparently something else was up then, because now it works!

Comment: I'd suggest not pasting in vim help text.  That first blurb is a perfect example of how unhelpful it can be.  Defining grep in terms of make doesn't help someone if they don't know how make works.  :grep! would be a simple enough and complete answer.  Though I have to agree with the OP that it's a bit wonky.  Sometimes just plain :grep doesn't open the first error.  Oh, and it's SUPER confusing that they're called "errors" instead of "matches".

Comment: I agree with @Milimetric; that first line is more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .vimrc:

```
    let g:EasyGrepOpenWindowOnMatch=0
```

EasyGrep has many options that can control how it behave. Type `:GrepOptions` for a listing of all of these.