# Function to open a file and navigate to a specified line number

Tags: function, vim

I have the output of recursive `grep` (actually `ag`) in a buffer, which is of the form `filename:linenumber: ... [match] ...`, and I want to be able to go to the occurrence (file and line number) currently under the cursor. [This](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/30.html) told me that I could execute normal-mode movements, so after extracting the *file:line* portion, I wrote this function:

```
function OpenFileNewTab(name)
    let l:pair=split(a:name, ":")
    execute "tabnew" get(l:pair, 0)
    execute "normal!" get(l:pair, 1) . "G"
endfunction
```

It is supposed to open the specified file in a tab and then do `<lineno>G`, like I am able to do manually, to go to the specified line number. However, the cursor just stays on line 1. What am I doing wrong?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440046/vim-script-to-open-file-at-certain-line-number), by title alone, would be an exact duplicate, but it talks locating symbols in other files, while I already have the locations at hand.

**Edit**: My mappings for *grep* / *ag* are as follows:

```
nnoremap <Leader>ag :execute "new \| read !ag --literal -w" "<C-r><C-w>" g:repo \| :set filetype=c<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>gf ^v2t:"zy :execute OpenFileNewTab("<C-r>z")<CR>
```

To get my *grep* / *ag* results, I put the cursor on the word I want to search and enter `<leader>ag`, then, in the new buffer, I put the cursor on a line and enter `<leader>gf` - it selects from the start up to the second colon and calls `OpenFileNewTab`.

**Edit 2**: I'm on Cygwin, if it is of any importance - I doubt it.

Comment: I think the two exec cmds are missing `.` before `get(...)`.  Also how did you do the grep? Personally I feel it is handy to have grep/ag result in qf and jump here and there...

Comment: You have to leave space after tabnew and normal commands.

Comment: You can put a bar (`|`) and combine both commands in a single execute funtion. That should solve it.

Comment: @Kent, see the edited question for grep.

Comment: @Kent you don't need the '.' `exe` will then join the argument with spaces

Comment: @SibiCoder, on your first suggestion, I didn't get where exactly I should put the space, could you clarify please? On the second, I tried `execute "tabnew " . get(l:pair, 0) "\| normal! " . get(l:pair, 1) . "G"`, with and without the pipe escape, and still the same. I'm working on cygwin, but I doubt that would mean any difference.

Comment: your function call looks correct. You should first test it, with a manual string, e.g. `call OpenFileNewTab('/cygdrive/c/temp/foobar.vim:20')` I suppose, your mappings is wrong. It looks strange

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: great! I was using `execute` instead of `call` in the mapping, and, probably, the file being open was just a side effect. But I think the normal command should've been executed and left a side effect as well - what do you think? If that last bit of confusion is cleared up and you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I agree with @Kent. You probably want to look into using the quickfix list. You can get a taste for the quickfix list via the following Vimcasts episode: [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt thank you... I always concatenate the parts of a command, didn't test without it. good to know it.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the built-in `:grep`?

Comment: @romainl, because, until this question, I had not heard of either `:grep` nor `quickfix`. I'm currently modifying my vimrc to use them.

Comment: @mcmlxxxvi Since you are new to the quickfix list here is a quick [overview](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7235/778).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you set `&grepprg` to call ag ?

```
" according to man ag
set grepprg=ag\ --vimgrep\ $*
set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m
" And then (not tested)
nnoremap <Leader>ag :grep -w <c-r><c-w><cr>
```

As others have said in the comments, you are just trying to emulate what the quickfix windows already provides. And, we are lucky vim can call grep, and it has a variation point to let us specify which grep program we wish to use: `'grepprg'`.

Comment: After finding out about `:grep` and `quickfix`, I went that way. I've gotten it to [not require Enter after grep](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7905/autoreturn-after-external-command), [not jump to the first match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723841/prevent-vim-grep-from-opening-first-matching-file) and [automatically open the quickfix window](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_open_the_quickfix_window_on_:make). Only thing left is to make quickfix honor column numbers - `--column` is specified but with Enter it still goes to line start.

Comment: Suggested settings according to `man ag`: `set grepprg=ag\ --vimgrep\ $*` and `set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m`

Answer (score 0):

Use [file-line plugin](https://github.com/bogado/file-line). Pressing Enter on a line in the quicklist will normally open that file; file-line will make any filename of the form `file:line:column` (and several other formats) to open `file` and position to `line` and `column`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in quickfix I can already jump to the match line (although I don't know if/how to make it honor column numbers as well). And I like keeping third-party scripts to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I only found this (old) thread after I posted the exact same question on vi.stackexchange: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/39557/44764.  To help anyone who comes looking, I post the best answer to my question below as an alternative to the answers already given.

The `gF` command, like `gf`, opens the file in a new tab but additionally it also positions the cursor on the line after the colon.  (I note the OP defines `<leader>gf` so maybe vim/neovim didn't auto-define `gf` or `gF` at the time this thread was originally created.)